# how to normalize data in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I try to create a simple neural network by following [this example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification),however I have a problem when I want to normalize the data

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras


fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

train_images = test_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0
```

this is my code ,in the last 2 lines ,as you can see, I attempt to normalize the data as shown [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification#preprocess_the_data) , however after I execute this line the variable `training_images` has only 10,000 samples instead of 60,000 (like it was in the beginning) and now when I try to fit the model (`model.fit()`) I get an exception

> Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 10000 input samples and 60000 target samples.

And when I try to run this example without the normalization I get a 0.2 accuracy at best (while in the site they have much higher accuracy)
where did I go wrong here?

Comment: was your problem solved? then kindly accept the answer so the question can be closed :-)

Comment: yes, stackoverflow wanted me to wait 15 minutes before I can accept this answer.
thanks a lot

Comment: good to know the underlying mechanics! thank you sir :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the bug is a simple typo -

```
train_images = test_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0
```

you divide through `test_images` both times. change the first division to `train_images` and it should work